# In iOS is there a way to prevent auto spelling correction in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, autocorrect

I already implement textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: as shown below. I need it to remove the prompt text and also to end editing. Do I need to add something else to it to turn off auto-correction? Or how else do I turn it off?

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([self.noteView.text isEqualToString:initialText]) {
        textView.text = @"";
        self.noteView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // initialText was lightGray
    } else if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `UITextView` instead of `UITextField` if you are only allowing one line? BTW - your code won't handle a user pasting in lots of text with a bunch of newlines in it.

Comment: @maddy: true. I'll look into changing to UITextField. The first version of this app was different and did expect several lines but later I changed it to expect only one line and didn't change the class.

Comment: @maddy: After looking at the previous answer you cited I now found UITextInputTraits and see that it does indeed let me specify no autocorrection. Many thanks. But I can't accept your answer because you didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it on storyboard. Select `UITextView` and check it:[image]

If you don't user storyboard, you can use this code:

```
yourTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Comment: Thanks that's good to know but I'm not making this UITextView in a storyboard.

Comment: @RobertL you can set it in code too. Check my edit answer.